# Use log4j in a tomcat with security manager

Tags: tomcat, log4j, securitymanager

The question is: is it necessary to give read permissions to **tomcat-juli.jar** for the **log4j.properties** when you use log4j for tomcat and you are running with **security manager**? http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j

My ${catalina.base}/conf/catalina.policy

```
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.base}/bin/tomcat-juli.jar" {
        .../...
        permission java.io.FilePermission
         "${catalina.base}${file.separator}lib${file.separator}log4j.properties", "read";
        .../...
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Luis

Comment: Have you tried doing it without read permissions? It seems like you could have answered this more quickly by trying it than posting on SO...

Comment: Hello Chris, of course that I have tried without the permissions. The aim of my question is to find out if my solution is correct or if it is just a workaround.... By the way it does not work without permissions. Anyway thanks for comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat comes by default with a `conf/catalina.policy` file that covers its default configuration for use under a Java Security Manager. If you want to use log4j, then yes, you *will* have to allow `tomcat-juli.jar` to read `conf/log4j.properties`.